# Customer can not redirect to my account page after create and login post action

Tags: magento-1.9, login, register

Site does not redirect to my account page after create account or login button click. *New account mail is sending properly at the time of registration*. But the page still redirect to login page itself.

**It works properly in localhost, but shows this error in live server**

Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: Did you check your php error log?

Comment: Have you tried other web browsers?

Comment: Tried in Mozilla Firefox. Sometimes it leads to account page. Not always.

Comment: Have a look through http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store/429#429 to see if you can see any error messages that occur with your system.